# How to protect routes on a client server with JWT generated from my RESTful backend API?

Tags: node.js, routes, jwt

I was attempting to build a signup/signin application using Nodejs. By looking at the articles, I came to know that it's a good structure to design your app so that your backend is actually a RESTful API and your client accesses that API. (Both client & server running on different servers, whereas the client is just a plain old static file server).

Now things went smooth until I had to sign users in. When the API endpoint (/signin) with the specific data is accessed, the data is validated against the database and if Okay, I am signing a JSON Web Token and passing it along to the client.

But the problem is that with this, I can only secure routes on my API i.e. I can only enforce that a user must be signed in to access a specific backend API endpoint.

But what can I do to enforce the same thing on my client with this JWT? For example, if in my client I have dashboard.html and I want it only accessible to signed in users, a user can go ahead and get a JWT generated. But how does this JWT come into play about restricting client routes?

My Signin Route:

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
var data = req.body;

if (!exists(data.username) || !exists(data.password))
    return res.status(422).json({
        message: 'All fields are required'
    });

const users = db.get('users');
users
    .findOne({
        username: data.username,
        password: shajs('sha256').update(data.password).digest('hex')
    })
    .then((user) => {
        if (user) {
            jwt.sign({
                _id: user._id,
                username: user.username
            }, 'keyboard_cat', {
                expiresIn: '1h'
            }, (err, tok) => {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'OK',
                    token: tok
                });
            });
            return;
        }

        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Invalid Username or Password.'
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: JWT can be only verified at backend. So you might want to check validity of JWT by an API call before loading the markup on client.

Comment: @tbking So essentially I will have to fire up another Node server on my client too? Right? Because as I said right now its just a static file server that does nothing but serves up files?

Comment: That depends on your implementation but the static javascript file can call the Node.js API server. There's no need for another server. The API server which issued the JWT can only verify the JWT. The client side javascript need to hit the API server.

Comment: @tbking if it will only be a client js file which would call the Node API, wouldn't a user be able to get that js file and make changes however he wants to access static protected routes? (because a client js file will have to be executed in the browser, hencing making it changeable by the client to access protected routes on client)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional render on the front-end side. You can fire an api with the api token (generated from '/signin' api) which will tell you wether the api token is valid or not whenever you enter the route. 
On the basis of the response from the server about the token you can decide which page to render (normal one or the unauthorised page).

There is also a better approach, send the api token in every route in the header, and if the token is malformed or invalid return 401 error from backend. Catch this error globally(or you can use response interceptor which is provided by [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)) and then do conditional rendering.

Comment: But for all this I would need to use node on my client server too, which makes sense. But if I have to use node on both my client and server, what is the point of separating them both? Before I thought that client remains a static file server (no node, no php, just a plain server) but clearly now, to do client route protection I will need node to send token to backend for validation?

Comment: Obviously client server should serve the static file.You don not need to render html page and send that page over the network. Single page Application which uses framework like React they use this type of strategy to decide which page to open in client side only. You have to write backend middleware in express which checks and validates JWT token on each route. Same can be done in client side. It can be implemented by using hook which should be fired when your route changed.